# How to adjust width and spacing of MicroCharts-Barchart in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, charts, xamarin.forms

I am using MicroCharts-Barchart to implement charts in Xamarin forms application. I want to set width of the bar and also spacing between bars, but I could not find any property to set this

Below is the code snippet I am using

**Xaml**

```
 <forms:ChartView x:Name="Chart4"  
                         HeightRequest="400"
                          />
```

**.cs file code**

```
public partial class ChartsPage : ContentPage
{

    List<Entry> entries = new List<Entry>
    {
        new Microcharts.Entry(200)
        {
            Color=SKColor.Parse("#FF1943"),
            Label ="January",
            ValueLabel = "200",

        },
        new Entry(400)
        {
            Color = SKColor.Parse("00BFFF"),
            Label = "March",
            ValueLabel = "400"
        },
        new Entry(-100)
        {
            Color =  SKColor.Parse("#00CED1"),
            Label = "Octobar",
            ValueLabel = "-100"
        },
        };
    public ChartsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Chart4.Chart = new BarChart() { Entries = entries };
    }

 }
```

And it shows like below

[image: Screenshot]

If MicroCharts does not have this feature, please suggest if there is any other library which has this feature.

Answer (score 2):

**XAML:**

You need to set the HorizontalOptions as StartAndExpand as follows:

```
<forms:ChartView x:Name="Chart4" HeightRequest="400" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
```

**.cs File Code:**

You need to set the Width of the Chart = NumberOfBars X BarWidth as follows:

```
public ChartsPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Chart4.Chart = new BarChart() { Entries = entries };

    //Set the WidthRequest of your Chart based on the following calculation.
    //Here, barWidth will be the width of the Bar in your Chart
    int barWidth = 50;
    Chart4.WidthRequest = entries.Count * barWidth;
}
```

To set the spacing between bars, use Margin as follows:

```
Chart4.Chart = new BarChart() { Entries = entries, Margin = 20 };
```

Hope this will help you.